# Why is Shabbat the only day of the week that is given a name in Tanach

Tags: shabbat, tanach

Why is Shabbat the only day of the week that is given a name in Tanach where as all the other days of the week aren't given a name in Tanach?

Comment: Why should it be otherwise? Shabbat is clearly the most distinct and in need of a name. For reference, numerous other languages have not named the days. (Or named them by numbers as in Russian).

Comment: I disagree with the premise. Shabbat is not a day of the week. It's a holiday which happens to always fall on the same day of the week. The day of the week is Yom HaShevi'i.

Comment: @DoubleAA has an excellent point! Another possibility is that "Shabbat" also can mean "week" (as in its usage in the verse regarding the counting of the Omer). As a matter of fact, if I correctly recall, the use of the name "Shabbat" for this day doesn't appear in the Torah until the story of the mahn. Even there, it could be argued that it means "resting". Regardless, look over the Shabbat Kiddush, maybe. Yes, the verbal form "Shavat" is used at the beginning. And the ending bracha says *Mekadesh Hashabbat*, which is the only reference to the name of the day. But it could also mean "the rest"

Comment: @DoubleAA - "It's a holiday which happens to always fall on the same day of the week. The day of the week is Yom HaShevi." This is very close to sounding that the two are separate. They are not. The seventh day is Shabbat, they are one and the same. It's not a holiday that falls out on the seventh day. The "holiday" IS the seventh day.

Comment: @MordechaiB. I disagree. Consider how Tosefet Shabbat is part of Shabbat but doesn't occur on Yom HaShevi'i. (More importantly, you have provided no source or reasoning for your claim.)

Comment: @MordechaiB. An analogy - The yeshiva has Mishmar on Thursday. Thursday is the name of the 5th day of the week. Just because mishmar occurs on the 5th day of the week, is that day suddenly called "mishmar"?

Comment: Keep in mind within my comment as well as my answer, is that I am focusing solely on the premise in your question that you state that the **Torah** calls the 7th day of the week Shabbat. That does not detract or contradict the idea that people have assigned that name to the 7th day, and that is what WE call it.

Comment: Besides, the Torah does give each day a name: Yom Rishon (Echad), Yom Sheini, Yom Shlishi, etc.

Comment: וַיְכַל אֱלֹקים בַּיּוֹם הַשְּׁבִיעִי מְלַאכְתּוֹ אֲשֶׁר עָשָׂה וַיִּשְׁבֹּת בַּיּוֹם הַשְּׁבִיעִי מִכָּל מְלַאכְתּוֹ אֲשֶׁר עָשָׂה: (בראשית ב:ב)

Comment: @DonielF I see that you were careful regarding what the Torah calls the "first" day. A bit further proof to the points made. Not only do the days of the week have no unique names, but even according to the Torah there is no "first" day of the week! Hmmm ... maybe warrants a separate question on that?

Comment: @Chaim I think I understand why you cited that verse. But, I don't think the majority of our readers do. You may want to explain things, and, for that matter, include it as part of an answer, assuming it doesn't duplicate one already here. Speaking of your comment ... Shabbat Shalom

Comment: @DanF HKB''H defining the seventh day as Shabbos is different than a minhag in yesvhivos.

Comment: @Double AA There is a larger discussion what tosefet Shabbos is. If it's just a prohibition to do work, it's not actually Shabbos and there is no problme that it is not occurring on the seventh day. If it is SHabbos, than in reality we are stretching the time of the seventh day.

Comment: @MordechaiB. I know. So what?

Comment: @MordechaiB. I agree 100%, see my answer, below as well as my above comment. I think OP was asking, specifically what the Torah calls it; not what we call it. Analagous - We called yesterday "Pesach Sheini". There is no such name like that in the Torah. If there were, then Pesach Sheini would have to be celebrated for 7 or 8 days!

Comment: @MordechaiB. the reason for the *tosefet* applies to Yom Tov as well. So, it is not because of Shabbat. It is because of a rule of adding from *kodesh* to *chol*. It has, technically, nothing to do with the name of the day, itself.

Answer (score 5):

As @DoubleAA mentioned, "Shabbat is not a day of the week. It's a holiday which happens to always fall on the same day of the week. The day of the week is Yom HaShevi'i".

There are many verses that prove this point. But, perhaps the clearest example comes from [Vayikra 23:2-3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9754&st=&pgnum=306). I will summarize the concept rather than do a literal translation.

Verse 2 starts with an introduction saying "These are my holidays that you should make holy". In other words, the Torah is already stating that what will be coming is a list of holidays.

Verse 3 says - You shall work for 6 days, and the 7th day shall be a Shabbat. Meaning, a "rest day". Note that the day itself is referred to as just "the seventh day". It is still a holiday, that doesn't change things. The holiday itself is called "Shabbat", and it occurs on the 7th day of the week.

See also [*Sforno's* explanation](http://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.31.17?lang=bi&with=Sforno&lang2=en) of the phrase וביום השביעי שבת - he says it means that you should rest from your work. It does not mean, "The seventh day should be called 'Shabbat'."

Assuming permission from @Chaim, I'm copying the verse that he cited in his comment:

> וַיְכַל אֱלֹקים בַּיּוֹם הַשְּׁבִיעִי מְלַאכְתּוֹ אֲשֶׁר עָשָׂה
>   **וַיִּשְׁבֹּת** בַּיּוֹם הַשְּׁבִיעִי מִכָּל מְלַאכְתּוֹ אֲשֶׁר עָשָׂה:
>   (בראשית ב:ב)‏

My translation of above verse from Breishit ([Gen. 2:2](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8166#v=2))

> G-d finished, on the seventh day, all the work that he did. He **rested**
>   on the seventh day from all the work that he did.

Generally, when we learn Torah, and we want to understand the definition of a word, we look for its first occurrence in the Torah.

There are two points to be learned from the above verse. First, you can see that the 7th day of the week is referred as exactly that - the 7th day. You don't see it called "Shabbat" anywhere.

Second, we see the word וַיִּשְׁבֹּת which has the root form שבת meaning "to rest".

Comment: I was going to add the verse from Bereishis, but forgot about it. (Would upvote again if I had the ability to :p)

Answer (score 4):

I once heard in a Shiur that by specifically not giving names to other days of the week we are given easy opportunities to merit in the Mitzva of "remembering the Shabbos" on a regular basis. By saying yom rishon, yom sheni etc. it is automatically referencing rishon and sheni to what - to The Shabbos.

[DanF adds:] This concept is an integral part of the 4th (of the 10) commandment, זכור את יום השבת לקדשו - Remember the Shabbat day to sanctify it. Many siddurim include mentioning this verse in the sentence just preceding the recital of the daily Psalm in *Shacharit*.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, sol. Thanks for the great answer. I am adding an additional point to your answer. If it is incorrect or needs to be amended, let me know. You may need a bit higher reputation score to edit your answers, at this point.